Next-auth refresh tokens
Each time auth() is called, the jwt() callback is triggered in the server components. But if the validity period of the token has expired and new tokens have been installed, all these auth work with the old tokens. That is, I call auth() 10 times - jwt() is triggered 10 times, which has the same accessExpiresAt, even if I set a new time. The validity period of the token is set low for the development time. I am using "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.20"
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: user.accessToken,
          refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
          accessExpiresAt: Date.now() + 1000 * 20,
          refreshExpiresAt: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        };
      } else if (Date.now() < token.accessExpiresAt) {
        return token;
      } else {
        try {
          const {
            data: { accessToken, refreshToken },
          } = await AuthApi.refresh(token.refreshToken);

          token.accessToken = accessToken;
          token.refreshToken = refreshToken;
          token.accessExpiresAt = Date.now() + 1000 * 20;
          token.refreshExpiresAt = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;

          return token;
        } catch (e) {
          return token;
        }
      }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken as string;
      session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken as string;

      return session;
    },
  },

I tried to output the validity time of the token, but it turned out that the new validity time was already after the lines
  token.accessExpires = Date.now() + 1000 * 20;

  console.log('New Access Expires:', token.accessExpires);

But on subsequent calls to auth(), the time was still old
async jwt({ token, user }) {
  if (user) {
       return {
         ...token,
         accessToken: user.accessToken,
         refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
         accessExpiresAt: Date.now() + 1000 * 20,
         refreshExpiresAt: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
       };
  }

  console.log('Current time:', Date.now(), 'Access Expires:', token.accessExpires);

  if (Date.now() < token.accessExpires) {
    return token;
  }

  console.log("Token expired");

  token.accessExpires = Date.now() + 1000 * 20;

  console.log('New Access Expires:', token.accessExpires);

  return token;
}

Current time: 1724634029881 Access Expires: 1724634029897
 GET /ru-ru 200 in 54ms
Current time: 1724634030380 Access Expires: 1724634029897
Token expired
New Access Expires: 1724634050381

